# Cannot Select Text Inside Z-Index/Position Div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a website where I have several divs positioned in-front of a background div by using `z-index` and `position:absolute`. This background div will be transformed later into a content carousel so it is vital that its text are selectable. My current code does not allow for the text and link to be selected and I am wondering how would I fix this.

http://jsfiddle.net/6fwf9/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="header" class="box">header</div>
<div id="bg">
    Cannot highlight this text <br>
    <a href="">Cannot click on this link</a>
</div>
<div class="box">content</div>​
```

CSS:

```css
.box { width: 150px; height:50px; background:aqua; margin:20px; }
#header { margin-bottom: 150px; }
#bg { width:200px; height:200px; padding-top:100px; background:pink; 
     position:absolute; top:0; z-index:-10;}​
```

**EDIT** - Image of what I am trying to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TF99.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just saw your picture, This is how I would do it.

```
<div id="bg">
    <div id="container">
        Cannot highlight this text
        <br>
        <a href="javascript:void();">Cannot click on this link</a>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="header" class="box">header</div>
<div class="box">content</div>
```

And for the CSS, Please take notes that I put border around the container to show where it is and what is the width and height

```
.box{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    background: cyan;
    top:150px;
    left:20px;
}

#bg{
    background-color:pink; 
    width:200px; 
    height:170px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}
#header{
    position:absolute;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;          
    z-index:2;
    background: cyan;
}
#container{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

The only thing left is you play with your dimention.
Actualy I put everything absolute exept the container.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do this as the `#bg` and its contents must stay in the same div otherwise my carousel will not be happy.

Comment: It seems like you should change the carousel's functionality then.  What @Manuel is recommending is the most logical structure for your div.

Comment: I just updated the code if the bg id you can't touch it. Just wrap your code into other div and remove the margin-bottom 150px for your header.

Comment: I've edited my post to include an image of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I also looked at your updated code but it doesn't do exactly what I am trying to do. I've added an image to my post.

Comment: Ah... I understand how to do it. You pretty much just used `position:absolute;` to place the `div`s where it needs to go. I'll try to integrate it into my page and hopefully everything will go well. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution integrated beautifully into my project.

Comment: Whenever you have a problem like this, always add borders to know exactly the dimension and location of each DIV element. It's highly probable that they are overlayed. Be very careful with aboslute position and padding because the padding will make it look OK but the DIV couble be overlaying other containers. Instead of padding, use margin, which changes the start position of the container.
I had the same problem and I fixed it after adding border, realizing that the containers were overlayed and changing padding to margin. 
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the overlaid elements (`.box`) don't sit in front of the text content, if they are to be selectable.  That means positioning them some other way than by using margins.  This example works because the boxes uses absolute positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/2pPKz/

Alternatively, if the background is to become a carousel, couldn't you worry about it when it's actually a carousel, and move it to the front then?

Comment: I have already implemented the carousel, but did not include the code in the post. Your solution works on JSFiddle, but when I copy+paste it into a blank .html page it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the bottom margin of the Header is over the text. I sugest you to change the way you are doing things here. Why don't you just make elements be inside the bg box?

```
<div id="bg">
  <div id="header" class="box">header</div>
  <p>Cannot highlight this text <a href="javascript:void();">Cannot click on this link</a></p>
  <div class="box">content</div>​
</div>
```

With static position? Even if you want to use absolute positioning, you could have everything inside the bg div and have it with position:relative, so the elements inside will be positioned absolutely respected to it.

Comment: So when I am using `margin-bottom` on a `div` the browser will essentially extend the vertical space of the div over top of my `#bg` which is creating my problem?

Comment: I like your solution of including my `#header` into my `#bg`, but unfortunately I cannot do that as I need to make my code very modular.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Regarding to your specific problem, could you tell me how does the carousel works? in order to help you to redesign the layout and CSS rules and keep the carousel working. And as a personal advice I suggest you to use classes instead of IDs for styling. If you need the ID's for JS, just keep them for that and give classes to the elements too for styling purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I've only used IDs when I thought that element would appear only once on the page. I am using SlidesJS for my carousel which wraps the entire carousel into its own div. Each element in the slideshow is then in its own seperate div within the SlidesJS div. I've also modified my original post to include an image of what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only way to do what you're trying to do is to split up the background and the text content for the slider.

That means each slide would need to consist of a background div that is absolutely positioned behind the content, and a content div that is absolutely positioned in front of everything else.

Comment: I can't split up the background and its content into two separate container as that would not work well with the carousel.